# Is there any plugin for goto Flickr Page for jQuery?

Tags: jquery-plugins, flickr

i am developing a website and I want to know if there is a plugin with a button for: Goto Flicker Page, like the image below

[image]

Is there any jquery plugin that can do this?

Comment: You should add a link to the flickr page on the image.

Comment: is there any plugin for this like, "Like" button of facebook?

Comment: The facebook Like button registers the likes at Facebook's end. As far as I understand, the button you're willing to add, is only a link to a Flickr Page. If not, then please add more details what the button should do when one clicks on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the link on the image of your flickr account, there is no plugin for this like "Facebook Like" button.